# Can I use google inside search data to return specific information

Tags: freebase, google-custom-search

I have been trying to develop an app that references [google inside search](http://www.google.com.au/insidesearch/) data.

Within the following picture, I would like to extract the picture, name, description, and opened. And display only that information as a result.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/waIEC.jpg]

I have been looking at google custom search, but i cant seem to find out any information on using this data contained within "google inside search".

If anyone knows how I could reference this information and extract selected information within an app that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge base i wanted to use is called Freebase. Once i got the correct terminology it was simple to work out. Google provide heaps of doco on this.